# In html, width and hight parameters crop my picture instead of scaling it. Why?

Tags: html, css, image, scaling

I have a webpage with a css style file. 
When I try to **scale** the header2.png in the code below, the picture gets **cropped** instead.

Any idea Why?

```
#header {
    background:url(images/bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; 
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
} 
#logo a {
    background:url(images/header2.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
    width: 800px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:10;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, position:absolute makes it crop rather than resize

Comment: Could you post the HTML too please.

Comment: Try placing the image in a wrapper div, position the div with absolute, and then take position:absolute out of the image's CSS.

Comment: Thanks echolocation. I changed to "position: relative", but still didn't work. I'll try your later suggestion then!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add the HTML code to your answer, and any other information that could help to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the background-size CSS property in order to get the picture to scale. One option you can use is to get the image to cover the header proportionally, like this...

```
#logo a { 
     background:   url(images/header2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
     width: 800px; 
     height: 80px;  
     position: absolute; 
     top:0;
     left:10;
     background-size: cover;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
     }
```

Of course, you can experiment with this by changing "cover" to pixels or percentages. For more information on resizing the background in CSS... visit http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot! (unfortunately I can't upvote, cause I don't have the reputation for it)

Comment: Agree with the answer. Basically OP is setting size for container but forgets to scale background properly. BUT, given the BAD rep w3cschools has, i think it's better to offer people the MDN docs instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbackground-size

Comment: Thanks for the link! I just came out of University, so they drummed W3Schools into our heads! Need to drum it back out! By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answers your question, feel free to mark as the answer :)

Comment: @Matt, I tried what you suggestion but it didn't work for me. I admit I don't know much about html/css coding. However, I just want a simple scaling of image.

Comment: @Matt, okay it works now!! I changed to "cover" to pixels and it works just fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you re-size your header2.png image to the size at which you want.

Comment: No, it's the opposite. The image is in the right size, but for some reason the code scales it up !